# Streaming JSON with AFNetworking on IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, json, streaming, afnetworking

What would be the most elegant way to receive data from a streaming JSON API using AFNetworking? AFNetworking provides excellent support for receiving non-streaming data from JSON APIs, but I couldn't find any examples of streaming JSON.

Comment: Did you ever get something like this working?

Comment: As far as I remember I managed to implement a very simple JSON streaming example, but very soon after that my interest in the IOS project I needed this for (i.e. a CampFire client) dropped. Nothing finished unfortunately ever came out of this. :)

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AFNetworking does not have a built-in streaming SAX-style JSON operation, but it should be straight forward to create your own.

- Create a subclass of `AFJSONRequestOperation`
- Use the `outputStream` property of the operation during initialization to hook it up to a JSON parser that supports SAX-style parsing (such as [Yajl](https://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc)). The parser will read data and build up the JSON object as it comes in
- Hook up the `responseJSON` property to read the cached object from the parser
- ...or depending on how you're doing streaming, you may need to add a new property that defines a block to execute when new JSON objects come back (e.g. `setReceivedJSONBlock:((^)(void (id JSON))block`). This block will probably be triggered by delegate methods sent from the parser (e.g. `<YAJLParserDelegate> -parserDidEndDictionary:`).

If you are able to get this working, I would encourage you to publish and share this with others. I think this could be useful to quite a few people.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try the suggested approach!

Comment: This is not going to work that easily with AFNetworking. First, AFURLConnectionOperation 's method -connection:didReceiveData: is not correctly implemented. It only works for streams which always do consume ALL bytes provided by the connection. This includes file streams and memory streams. However, in order to "interface" the stream API of a parser with a NSURLConnectionDelegate a more elaborated approach is necessary involving some sort of "synchronous queue" as a means to transport the data and a paired stream which have a fixed size buffer.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on this? How to hook up outputStream to JSON parser?