# How to streaming JSON (chunked transfer encoding) parsing using AFNetworking on ios

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking-2

I am new to ios development. I want to use AFNetworking to receive data from a streaming JSON API in our server.
When I send a request to the server, the connection will be kept until something wrong with the network. Our server use the comet method to push messages to my ios client. There are two types of messages:Heart-beat message for reachability monitoring and application message for display. The messages are all Chunked transfer encoding and are only json data with few bytes. The server sends heart-beat messages to the client if there is no application data related to the user of the application.

I find there is a question similar to mine.

[Streaming JSON with AFNetworking on IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366959/streaming-json-with-afnetworking-on-ios)

But the author of the AFNetworking said that "AFNetworking does not have a built-in streaming SAX-style JSON operation..." . Since the question was asked 2 years ago, I checked the API of the new version of AFNetworking, but I couldn't find any examples of streaming JSON. I wonder whether the new version of AFNetworking(such as 2.0 or 2.2) has support for streaming JSON?  If no support, is there exist some other kinds of library to parse the chunked encoding JSON data? Could you give me some demo code?

Thanks forward.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen anything finished and ready for you to use out of the box for JSON streaming.  The AFNetworking 2 release candidate included [`AFEventSource`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0-RC2/Classes/AFEventSource.html),  which maintained an open HTTP connection with a server, and streamed events.  However, it is not included in the stable AFNetworking branch.

You can also take a look at [`AFRocketClient`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFRocketClient/tree/master/AFRocketClient) but you'll need to do some work before putting this into a production app.