# How can I implement stream parsing for large json files in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking-2

I am creating an application using xcode, and using AFNetworking for requests. I have created REST based APIs for fetching data, based on user's inputs. For some parameters, I have very large JSON files in response. Now, the api hit request itself takes more than 4-5 seconds for such cases. I am looking to implement json stream parsing for such cases. Please provide me with a basic example of how to approach this.

Also, if not clear, by stream parsing I mean when I will send a hit to the api, it will open a stream, and i will keep getting the json response in parts as it keeps reading. The whole process might still take same time, but I am getting data as it keeps streaming.

Comment: Looks like dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366959/streaming-json-with-afnetworking-on-ios

Comment: i saw that.. it's 2+ years old with no (helpful) answer.. I need some more hints.. :)

Comment: What was the question?

Comment: @Andy: sorry, I didnt get you.. You mean i should explain my question? or the one nielsbot posted?
I am looking to implement stream parsing in chunks in ios for large json data..

Comment: what problem do you face implementing this? Share some code, we may help out

Comment: i am using AFNetworking, and trying to do something on the lines of this answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9368075/3636866
Now, if i am using JSON parser such as YAJL in this example, how do i hook up outputStream to it?
And then how do I hook up the responseObject property to read the cached object from the parser?
Any example line of code?

Comment: You see here we help people that display an effort. Where is effort in reading YAJL documentation? No effort. Matt gave a detailed response to how to implement streaming parser. Having all of this should take 30 mins to put it all together.

Comment: ok, thanks @Andy.. :)
i think many programmers who are starting with ios find this tricky, (despite reading docs) since they are not familiar.. nonetheless, i get your drift, i will try this and will let you know if i get stuck.. :)

Comment: @avnishkgaur that makes a lot of sense, because instead of learning basics and building your own foundation, people jump straight to difficult tasks they don't understand.